# Eaccss error in node.js and express

Tags: node.js

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'public/images/598ABFBB-9BD0-4892-81F3-B0B827E7C715'
    at Error (native)
```

> i am getting this error and node is stopped.
>   why this error occur?
>   I am getting the data from the other server and after that i am trying
>   to download the image into my folder which is inside public/images/

Comment: It says permission denied, did you check folder and file permissions?

Comment: i don't know how to check and give permissions in ubuntu

Comment: to check permissions, list files with `ls -l [path]` command and then you will see permissions.